# Optimizing mindmaps by finding the least amount of repetition

Tags: c#, algorithm

When using mindmaps, you order them based on how you think it fits best.

So for instance (tab means subtree)

```
requirements
  dinner
    food
    forks
    spoons
  breakfast
    food
    forks
```

this could be written using

```
food
  requirements at
    dinner
    breakfast
forks
  requirements at
    dinner
    breakfast
spoons
  requirements at
    dinner
```

What would an algorithm look like that finds the best sorting in the manner described. Best means, the least amount of repetition?

The 2nd example might not actually reduce repetition but it shows what is meant by sorting/reordering.

To elaborate further: when talking about repetition in this context I understand not having the same words/phrases more than once. In the first example, food is being repeated twice, as well as forks. Then we can reorder it as the second example shows. There we have the problem of dinner three times and breakfast two times but at least not food twice and forks twice. Goal is to have as little repetition as possible given a certain mindmap.

Comment: What do you mean by "least amount of redundancy?" Both of those orderings have the same information content and same amount of redundancy. Different redundancies, but the same number of redundancies.

Comment: @JimMischel This question has already been answered in the main post.

Comment: "This question has already been answered in the main post" - Where? My best assumption would be that, without "requirements" and "at", the first has 7 lines and the second has 8, so the first would have "less redundancy" (but perhaps it would be better to refer to it as 'memory used', although that may indicate a character count, or something other than 'redundancy'). But if both instances of "food", for example, would indicate the same node, both would have the same amount of memory used, as both has a node for each occurring value and 5 connections.

Comment: No, the question of what you mean by redundancy hasn't been answered. At least two of us have no idea what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @JimMischel Main post updated.

Comment: @Dukeling Main post updated.

Comment: My original point still stands: you have the same amount of redundancy either way.

Comment: @JimMischel We turn this around: what did you understand, what is my problem to you?

Answer (score 1):

When as in the example there are two kind of objects, and relations between them, this could be modeled as [weighted Vertex Cover in bipartite graphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/10821/what-is-an-algorithm-to-find-a-minimum-vertex-cover-on-a-bipartite-graph-with-we), where the weights are the degrees. For more general inputs, I am not really sure which ways of writing them would be allowed and what would be minimized.

Answer (score 1):

You have five relationships:

```
food, dinner
food, breakfast
forks, dinner
forks, breakfast
spoons, dinner
```

You can list them by item, or by meal. If you list by item, then you have three top-level nodes and five second-level nodes. If you list by meal, you have two top-level nodes and, again, five second-level nodes.

You can reduce the apparent repetition by choosing for the top level the side of the relationship that has the fewest unique items. In this case, there are two meals and three things that are required. So the top level should be meals. But understand that you're not reducing redundancy. You're reducing apparent repetition, but that's something else entirely.

But the whole discussion is largely academic. What really matters is what you're going to do with the data. That is, what questions are you going to ask? If the question is, "What do I need in order to serve dinner?" then arranging the data as shown in your first option is better. You can look up "dinner" and find exactly what you need.

If the question is "I have food and spoons, what meals can I serve?" then the other arrangement is easier to work with: you look up "food" and "spoons" and then union the results.

In truth, both questions can be answered with either arrangement of data, but one arrangement is more optimum than the other for a particular query. Typically you'd arrange the data so that the most common query can be answered quickly.

So the "best" arrangement depends on several things, chief among them is how you'll be using the data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, this is one of two problems:

**User Visualisation**

Offer sorting options to the user! Cover all bases, let them choose.

In my opinion, you want to go for the most logical layout (per the domain - probably similar to your data model) which is the first. Redundancy in information is preferable to obfuscation through optimization. Visual relationships are quicker to process than informational relationships which require your eye to jump around the screen.

**Relational Database Normalization**

Pick one method and profile it. The bottleneck will be the number of clauses you need to retrieve your data and that depends entirely upon usage.

Fundamentally speaking:

- If you have more utensils than meals, the 1st option is better.
- If you have more meals that utensils, the 2nd method is better.

If you have more than 2 layers, things get complicated ;)